# GraphQL usage with REST Endpoints in .NET Core 6.0

Tags: c#, angular, graphql, .net-6.0, graphql-js

Since I am new to GraphQL, I don't really know how to call a REST endpoint and query the fields accordingly. In particular, I want to fetch certain fields from the entire response of a GET API.

What I have learnt is GraphQL sends a `POST` request. How do I hit the `GET` endpoints ?

PS: we cannot use Apollo client in the project.

Comment: The question is unclear and shows a bit of confusion on what GraphQL is. There's no such thing as a REST endpoint. REST is an architectural style, not a protocol. All GraphQL services work over HTTP and can be called with an HTTP POST. Apollo Client makes this easier and adds a lot of features but in the end, it sends HTTP POST requests

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Call a GraphQL endpoint from C#? Or call a GraphQL endpoint written in C# from Angular? The server library you're using may already contain examples if not a full IDE. For example [HotChocolate](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v13/get-started-with-graphql-in-net-core#executing-a-query) contains an IDE that can be used to create, run and inspect queries. Some of them can even generate client code examples

Comment: Thanks for responding. The point here is not fetching from a graphql endpoint. We already have a normal endpoint (eg. myapiname/product which is of the type get). I instead of fetching the entire product, I want to fetch just a certain part of the product without using Apollo Client @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: You don't need Apollo Client. Simply typing the URL with the correct query in your browser will retrieve what you want. I posted an answer that shows exactly that

Answer (score 0):

While trying to find the docs that say GraphQL works with POST, I found the docs that show it can work with GET too, if you pass the entire query in the `query` query string parameter. The [Serving over HTTP - GET Request](https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/#get-request) section shows that this query :

```
{
  me {
    name
  }
}
```

Can be sent using GET with :

```
http://myapi/graphql?query={me{name}}
```

Variables and operation names can be passed as additional parameters:

> Query variables can be sent as a JSON-encoded string in an additional query parameter called variables. If the query contains several named operations, an operationName query parameter can be used to control which one should be executed.

To test this, I created a new minimal GraphQL services using HotChocolate's [Getting Started](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v13/get-started-with-graphql-in-net-core) example and tried this in a new browser tab:

```
http://localhost:5242/graphql?query={book{title}}
```

I got back a valid GraphQL response:

```
{
    "data": {
        "book": {
            "title": "C# in depth."
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have 2 questions regarding this -
Suppose there is an API endpoint available to me :-
(Get)Products
(Post)Products

 1. How do I define from the query in url, to be using the get endpoint.
/n
If the response from the endpoint is of the form: 
{
 "data":{
  Index : 1,
 },
 "results":{
  Id : 1,
  Name: 'Stack Overflow',
  Price :5,
  Currency : "$",
 },
}
 2. How do I query to fetch the things like id, name inside results without knowing the schema.